# Using docker swarm to execute singular containers rather than "services"

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I really enjoy the concept of having a cluster of docker machines available to execute docker services. I also like the additional features not available to singular docker containers (such as docker secret).

But I really have no need for long-standing services. My use case is to simply execute a bash script to use the docker swarm to take in an arbitrary number of finite commands, and execute each as a running docker container on the same docker image, while using the secrets loaded up with docker swarm's secrets.

Can I do this?
I do not want to have this container be "long running". I want it to run, and then exit with the output when the bash script loaded into the container is finished.

Comment: [There was a proposal](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/359) but no one cares.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the ideas presented in "[One-shot containers on Docker Swarm](https://blog.alexellis.io/containers-on-swarm/)" from **[alex ellis](https://github.com/alexellis)**.

You still neeeds to create a service, *but* with the right restart policy.
For instance, for a quick web server:

```
docker service create --restart-condition=none --name crawler1 -e url=http://blog.alexellis.io -d crawl_site alexellis2/href-counter
```

([`--restart-condition`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#running-as-a-job), not `--restart-policy`, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313541/using-docker-swarm-to-execute-singular-containers-rather-than-services/46313630#comment120356615_46313630) by [ethergeist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16174836/ethergeist))

> So by setting a restart condition of 0, the container will be scheduled somewhere in the swarm as a (task). The container will execute and then when ready - it will exit.
>
> If the container fails to start for a valid reason then the restart policy will mean the application code never executes. It would also be ideal if we could immediately return the exit code (if non-zero) and the accompanying log output, too.

For the last part, use his tool: [**alexellis/jaas**](https://github.com/alexellis/jaas).

> Run your first one-shot container:
>
> ```
> # jaas -rm -image alexellis2/cows:latest
> ```
>
> The `-rm` flag removes the Swarm service that was used to run your container.
>
> The exit code from your container will also be available, you can check it with `echo $?`.

Comment: `--restart-policy` changed to `--restart-condition`, https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#running-as-a-job

Comment: @ethergeist Thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly, and included your comment for more visibility.